# Java MergeSort using stacks

Tags: java, stack, mergesort

I'm kind of new to this but trying to learn as quickly as possible. I am trying to implement a merge sort using stacks. I have no errors as such in my code but i get an array out of bounds error when i run the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As i envision it, the merge sort function splits the stack in 2 (Left and Right) and then calls the merge function which sorts and merges them.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> myStack = new Stack<>();
    Random r = new Random();
    int size= 30;
    for (int i = 0; i < size;i++)
    {
        myStack.add(r.nextInt(200));
        System.out.println(myStack.peek());
    }
    MergeSort(myStack);
    System.out.println("-------");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(myStack.pop());
    }

}
private static Stack<Integer> MergeSort(Stack<Integer> input)
{
    Stack<Integer> Result;
    Stack<Integer> Left = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Integer> Right = new Stack<>();
    if (input.size() <= 1)
    {
        return input;
    }
    int midpoint = input.size() / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < midpoint; i++)
    {
        Left.add(input.get(i));
    }
    for (int i = midpoint; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        Right.add(input.get(i));
    }
    Left = MergeSort(Left);
    Right = MergeSort(Right);
    Result = Merge(Left, Right);

    return Result;
}

private static Stack<Integer> Merge(Stack<Integer> Left, Stack<Integer> Right)
{
    Stack<Integer> Result = new Stack<>();
    while (Left.size() > 0 && Right.size()>0)
    {
        if (Left.get(0) < Right.get(0))
        {
            Result.add(Left.get(0));
            Left.removeElementAt(0);
        }
        else
        {
            Result.add(Right.get(0));
            Right.removeElementAt(0);
        }
    }
    while (Left.size()> 0)
    {
     Result.add(Left.get(0));   
     Left.removeElementAt(0);
    }
    while (Right.size() > 0)
    {
      Result.add(Right.get(0));
      Right.removeElementAt(0);                    
    }
    return Result;
}
```

This is the console output.

run:
10
73
82
74
4
40
86
119
102
83
122
5
164
50
25
117
57
153
95
155
70
115
61
162
55
190
35
171
150

### 44

44
150
171
35
190
55
162
61
115
70
155
95
153
57
117
25
50
164
5
122
83
102
119
86
40
4
74
82
73
10
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: In your main method you don't receive the result of call to `MergeSort(myStack);`

Comment: Can you post the exception's stacktrace, please?

Comment: As an aside, to follow standard java conventions variables and method names should begin with lowercase letters.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I am working from an example made by a colleague who is not here to help so i decided just to copy names exactly. I shall use lower case in the future.
Not quite sure how to solve the problem with my main method, hence the post.

Comment: @NickB here you have a visual explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/23695092/3315914

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function Merge:
`if (Left.get(0) < Right.get(0))`
you wrote `Result.get(Left.get(0))` instead of `Result.add(Left.get(0))`

Another thing: in your main function when printing the sorted stack:
Do you really want to use `.peek()` (it only looks at the top of the stack)?

Comment: Thank you! Such a silly mistake. What should i use instead of .peek()? I tried pop but that doesn't seem to work. I now get the original stack printed in reverse. I have updated my code with the correction.

Comment: First thing: myStack = MergeSort(myStack) // get result of MergeSort (overrides the original stack). Second: use pop and in your Merge function you change the condition in your if-clause: `Left.get(0) > Right.get(0)`. But remember: after popping all the element your stack will be empty.