# Using Stacks for a Non-Recursive MergeSort?

Tags: java

my professor assigned a problem in which we must use Stacks (or Queues) to make a non-recursive MergeSort. The current code is as follows:

```
 private static void sort(Comparable[] a, int[] index, int[] aux, int lo, int hi) {
    if (hi <= lo) return;
    int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;

    sort(a, index, aux, lo, mid);
    sort(a, index, aux, mid + 1, hi);

    merge(a, index, aux, lo, mid, hi);
```

I'm not sure how to approach this problem, and any help would be appreciated. I know that i must use a while loop to emulate the recursion. But how can I split the actual values? Also, how can I keep track of the middle of the partitioned values?

I am really confused by the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Think about how recursion works -- you push the current state onto the program stack, process the new subset of the data, return the result to the caller, pop the previous state back off the stack and continue. All you're really doing in this exercise is to replace call/return with push-iterate-pop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most important thing is to understand how the algorithm works. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort):

> Conceptually, a merge sort works as follows:
>
> Divide the unsorted list into n sublists, each containing 1 element (a
>   list of 1 element is considered sorted). Repeatedly merge sublists to
>   produce new sorted sublists until there is only 1 sublist remaining.
>   This will be the sorted list.

[image: Mergesort animation]

**Solution 1**: With a queue.

---

```
static int[] mergeSortQueue(int[] A) {
        Queue<int[]> queue = new LinkedList<int[]>();


        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        {
            queue.add(new int[]{A[i]});
        }
        while (queue.size()>1)
        {
                int[] r = queue.poll();
                int[] l = queue.poll();
                int[] merged=merge(l, r);
                queue.add(merged);  
        }
        return queue.poll();


    }
```

---

Graphically,

[image: mergesort_queue]

---

**Solution 2**: With two stacks

---

This is a bit more complex.

It basically consists on merging the elements of the first stack, inserting them into the second stack, until only one remains.

```
static int[] mergeSortStacks(int[] A) {
        Stack<int[]> stack = new Stack<int[]>();
        Stack<int[]> stack2 = new Stack<int[]>();

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        {
            stack.push(new int[]{A[i]});
        }
        while (stack.size()>1)
        {
            while (stack.size()>1)
            {

                int[] r = stack.pop();
                int[] l = stack.pop();
                int[] merged=merge(l, r);
                stack2.push(merged);
            }
            while (stack2.size()>1)
            {

                int[] r = stack2.pop();
                int[] l = stack2.pop();
                int[] merged=merge(l, r);
                stack.push(merged);
            }
        }
        return stack.isEmpty() ? stack2.pop() : stack.pop();


    }
```

---

Graphically,

### [image]

Comment: Brilliant reply, thanks! Your two stack example won't work however with an array like `[7, 1, 5, 2, 9, 3]`, as both stacks will contain a single array when loops are done. So you can add  `if (!stack.isEmpty() && !stack2.isEmpty()) return merge(stack.pop(), stack2.pop());` before your return statement.

Comment: I think the two stack method incurs n^2 running time because it always merges a large array with a one or two element array.

Comment: Well, is a little less than that. Should be near n*log(n) running time

Answer (score 0):

```
private int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right) {
    int ll = left.length;
    int rl = right.length;

    int[] mergedArray = new int[ll + rl];
    int l = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (l < ll && r < rl) {
        if (left[l] < right[r]) {
            mergedArray[i++] = left[l++];
        } else {
            mergedArray[i++] = right[r++];
        }
    }
    while (l < ll) {
        mergedArray[i++] = left[l++];
    }
    while (r < rl) {
        mergedArray[i++] = right[r++];
    }
    return mergedArray;
}
```

Comment: The missing merge method for the queue implementation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).